# Beautifulsoup and AJAX-table problem

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am making a script that scrapes the games of the Team Liquid database of international StarCraft 2 games. (http://www.teamliquid.net/tlpd/sc2-international/games)

However I come accros a problem. I have my script looping through all the pages, however the Team Liquid site uses some kind of AJAX I think in the table to update it. Now when I use BeautifulSoup I can't get the right data.

So I loop through these pages:

http://www.teamliquid.net/tlpd/sc2-international/games#tblt-948-1-1-DESC

http://www.teamliquid.net/tlpd/sc2-international/games#tblt-948-2-1-DESC

http://www.teamliquid.net/tlpd/sc2-international/games#tblt-948-3-1-DESC

http://www.teamliquid.net/tlpd/sc2-international/games#tblt-948-4-1-DESC
etc...

When you open these yourself you see different pages, however my script keeps getting the same first page every time. I think this is because when opening the other pages you see some loading thing for a small amount of time updating the table with games to the correct page. So I guess beatifulsoup is to fast and needs to wait for the loading and updating of the table to be done.

So my question is: **How can i make sure it takes the updated table?**

I now use this code to get the contents of the table, after which I put the contents in a .csv:

```
html = urlopen(url).read().lower()
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = bs.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='table' and tag.has_key('id')
                and tag['id']=="tblt_table") 
rows = table.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr')
```

Comment: In the future you should think about using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) instead of BeautifulSoup. Go with lxml for speed, html5lib for robust parsing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you try to scrape a site using AJAX, it's best to see what the javascript code actually does. In many cases it simply retrieves XML or HTML, which would be even easier to scrape than the non-AJAXy content. It just requires looking at some source code.

In your case, the site retrieves the HTML code for the table control by itself (instead of refreshing the whole page) from a special URL and dynamically replaces it in the browser DOM. Looking at http://www.teamliquid.net/tlpd/tabulator/ajax.js, you'd see this URL is formatted like this:

*http://www.teamliquid.net/tlpd/tabulator/update.php?tabulator_id=1811&**tabulator_page=1**&tabulator_order_col=1&tabulator_order_desc=1&tabulator_Search&tabulator_search=*

So all you need to do is to scrape this URL directly with BeautifulSoup and advance the tabulator_page counter each time you want the next page.

Comment: thanks for you elborate response, I studied the .js file and now understand what is happening. However when I open your URI in my browser nothing returns. Could this have something to do with the fact that they use a GET request? http.open('GET', url + params, true); 

(url is http://www.teamliquid.net/tlpd/tabulator/update.php? and params is tabulator_id=1811&tabulator_page=1&tabulator_order_col=1&tabulator_order_desc=1&tabulator_Search&tabulator_search=)

Comment: No, GET request is what your browser would normally use. This page worked before for me, and it doesn't work now... Very strange.

Comment: it works now: it only works when you open the page with the table yourself and then copy the number and replace tabulator_id=xxxx with your number. I guess your 1811 was somekind of session specific! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't with just BeautifulSoup; it doesn't execute javascript for you.

You might have more luck with [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), assuming you don't want to try to parse the relevant javascript yourself and make the calls the AJAX would be making to get the data.

Answer (score 2):

For sites with dynamic content through AJAX and Javascript, I have used [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It doesn't require open a browser because it's in itself a fully scriptable web browser. PhantomJS is fast and includes native support for various web standards as DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON and Canvas.

If you aren't a JavaScript Ninja, You should look [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/), it is written over PhantomJS. It eases the process of defining a full navigation scenario and provides useful high-level functions.

Here an example about how CasperJS works:

[CasperJs and Jquery with chained Selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283908/casperjs-and-jquery-with-chained-selects/16300933#16300933)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the cause of your problem is that neither BeautifulSoup nor urllib will be able to execute the javascript inside the page.

Maybe, you should use selenium to open the page in a real browser, then extract the html when it is ready and parse it with BeautifulSoup.