# Unable to scrape name from google finance

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape name, url and description of companies as listed on google finance. So far I am successful in getting description and url but unable to fetch the name. In the source code of myUrl, name is 024 Pharma Inc. When I see the div, the class is named 'appbar-snippet-primary'. But still the code doesn't find it. I ma new to web scraping so may be I am missing something. Please guide me in this regard.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import csv

myUrl = 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=OTCMKTS%3AEEIG' 

r = urllib.urlopen(myUrl).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

name_box = soup.find('div', class_='appbar-snippet-primary')  # !! This div is not found
#name = name_box.text  
#print name

description = soup.find('div', class_='companySummary') 
desc = description.text.strip()  
#print desc

website = soup.find('div', class_='item')  
site = website.text  
#print site
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913280/beautifulsoup-and-ajax-table-problem and also https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlefinance

Comment: you can not find div 'appbar-snippet-primary' as this div is generated dynamically in javascript, you need `selenium` or `splash` to scrap this kind of web.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

myUrl = 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=OTCMKTS%3AEEIG' 

r = requests.get(myUrl).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

name = soup.find('title').text.split(':')[0]  # !! This div is not found
#print name

description = soup.find('div', class_='companySummary') 
desc = description.text.strip()  
#print desc

website = soup.find('div', class_='item')  
site = website.text
```

Answer (score -1):

write soup.find_all() instead of soup.find()