# Don't understand the cause of this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://ratings.fide.com/top_lists.phtml"
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
list = soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr",limit=10)
count = 1
for tr in list:
    title = tr.find("td").find("a").text
    _count = str(count)+"."
    print(f"{_count.ljust(3)} Oyuncu Adı:{title.ljust(55)}")
    count += 1
```

And it gives:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Why this code doesnt work?

Comment: Presumably because no tbody was found in the parsed HTML. Did you look at what soup actually contained?

Answer (score 1):

The content of the page is load through an Ajax call. Change the URL page to `a_top.php`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://ratings.fide.com/a_top.php"
html = requests.get(url).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table')

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    print(row)
```

See [Beautifulsoup and AJAX-table problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913280/beautifulsoup-and-ajax-table-problem)

Answer (score 0):

From the BeautifulSoup website:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foo' - This usually happens because you called find() and then tried to access the .foo attribute of the result. But in your case, find() didn’t find anything, so it returned None, instead of returning a tag or a string. You need to figure out why your find() call isn’t returning anything.

It looks like the web page you're grabbing doesn't use the tbody tag to display its data.